# Why is a forward declaration in a function declaration allowed?

Tags: c++, c++11

While reading about the visitor pattern I ran into this snippet of code:

```
virtual void visit(class Composite *, Component*) = 0;
```

This is a member function, and it seems to be forward declaring the class `Composite` inside its parameters. I tried this with just a normal function, like so:

```
void accept(class A a);
```

for some class `A` that I haven't declared or defined yet and the code worked fine. Why is this allowed? How, if at all, is it different from forward declaring before the line? Has anything changed recently in the standard in regards to this?

---

Many people are claiming this is a leftover of C, but then why does this code compile fine in C++, but not C?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int process(struct A a);

struct A{
    int x;
};

int process(struct A a){
    return a.x;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct A a = {2};
    printf("%d", process(a));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's mainly just leftover from C.

Comment: I don't see how `visit` could be forward declaring `Composite` by having it as a parameter. If anything `Composite` must be declared before `visit` in order for this to compile?

Comment: That's what I thought too, but it doesn't.

Comment: I just tried it and it works... never seen `class` as a keyword to a parameter, also confused now... +1

Comment: @asimes `Composite` does NOT technically have to be declared before `visit` since that's of a pointer type with 4 bytes.

Comment: @DeanSeo, It needs to be declared, but not necessarily defined.

Comment: @DeanSeo, This compiles: `class A { virtual void a(class B*) = 0; }; int main() { return 0; }` but this does not: `class A { virtual void a(B*) = 0; }; int main() { return 0; }`

Comment: @chris Yes, but it does NOT have to be declared 'before' `visit` as @asimes mentioned. You can declare it by having it as an function argument.

Comment: @asimes I do not see why the second provided example should compile okay. The compiler does not know the type `B` unless it's declared somewhere. On the other hand, `class B*` explicitly indicates that `B` is of a type.

Comment: Ultimately, it comes down to "C and C++ are two distinct languages, albeit with some common ancestry and surprisingly good interworking, but with different semantics in some places, and this is one of those many places".

Comment: The last part of your question might be better as a separate question. The behaviour of types being introduced by that differs between languages and that difference itself is rather unrelated to the original question. The part that remained quite well from C was the referral to a tag name.

Comment: @chris I only added that part to draw the line between it being a holdover from C and it being a partially different feature from C, I don't actually care about why it is invalid C, but rather why it is valid C++.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is called an *incomplete type*, and is a concept C++ inherited from C.

Incomplete types work this way: before you've defined a `class B` in your code, you can use `class B varname` as, say, an argument in function prototypes, or use pointers to this type as `class B* ptr` - anywhere where no details about a type besides its name are really needed.

Actually, you can write it differently - just put a `class B;` (which should work as a class *declaration*) before you use it as an incomplete type, and then you can write `B varname` instead of `class B varname`.

Pointers to incomplete types are often used with [*opaque pointers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer#C.2B.2B), which are probably the most common use of incomplete types in C++. Opaque pointers are described well enough in the linked Wikipedia article. Put short, it is a technique that allows your API to hide an entire class implementation.

Using the incomplete type syntaxis you describe in your question, the example code from Wikipedia:

```
//header file:
class Handle {
public:
    /* ... */

private:
    struct CheshireCat;        // Not defined here
    CheshireCat* smile;        // Handle
};

//CPP file:

struct Handle::CheshireCat {
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

can be rewritten as:

```
//header file:
class Handle {
public:
    /* ... */

private:
    struct CheshireCat* smile;        // Handle
};

//CPP file:

struct CheshireCat {
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

Note this: these code snippets are *not* equivalent, as the former defines a type `Handle::CheshireCat`, while the latter has it simply as `CheshireCat`.

**On the code you gave as an example**:

In C, the reason it doesn't compile is quite simple: the `struct A` in the function prototype is a declaration scoped to the function prototype, and thus it is different from the `struct A` which is declared latter. C and C++ have slightly different rules for this specific case. If you forward-declare the `struct` like this: `struct A;` before the function prototype, it will compile in both languages!

**Other notable uses of this syntaxis:**

This syntaxis has an important place as part of C++'s **backward compatibility with C**. You see, in C, after defining or forward-declaring a `struct` like this: `struct A {};` or `struct A;`, the type's actual name would be `struct A`. To use the name as `A`, you needed to use a `typedef`. C++ does the latter automatically, but allows you to use `A` both as `struct A` and `A`. Same goes for `class`-es `union`-s, and `enum`-s.

Actually, some argue this has a semantical importance. Consider a function with the following signature: `int asdf(A *paramname)`. Do you know what `A` is just by looking at the declaration? Is it a `class`, `struct`, `enum` or a `union`? People say that a signature like that can be made clearer in such a way: `int asdf(enum A *paramname)`. This is a nice way of writing self-documenting code.

Answer (score 5):

In C, structure names were not accessible without the `struct` keyword:

```
struct Foo {};

void bar(struct Foo foo) {...}
```

You could get around this by using a `typedef` as well:

```
typedef struct Foo {} Foo;

void bar(Foo foo) {...}
```

In C++, this remains for backward compatibility. It's been logically extended, including support for the `class` keyword instead of `struct`. `class Composite *` is almost equivalent to just saying `Composite *` in this regard. It is not necessarily used as a forward declaration, just accessing the type name.

Note that it can still be used to disambiguate if necessary:

```
struct Foo {};
void Foo();

int main() {
    Foo foo; //error: Foo refers to the function
    struct Foo foo; //okay: struct Foo refers to the class        
}
```

Now the same declaration can introduce a type name, like it does in your `accept` example and possibly does in the `visit` example. For a function at namespace scope, if the class being declared is not found, it will be declared in the namespace containing the function (see N4140 [basic.scope.pdecl]/7).

This means that the following will not compile due to the `struct`/`union` mismatch:

```
void foo(struct Bar bar);
union Bar;
```

The above code is roughly equivalent to:

```
struct Bar;
void foo(Bar bar);
union Bar;
```

Comment: *"for some class A that I haven't declared or defined yet and the code worked fine."* the question looks more about declaring an incomplete type as part of a function declaration. *"It is not a forward declaration, just accessing the type name"* actually, for `class Composite *` it is.

Comment: In C, you'd get a warning with the equivalent code: `void visit(struct Composite *, struct Component *)` introduces a new type, `struct Composite` which only exists in the scope of the function declaration, so you can never complete that type.  Maybe  the same doesn't apply to C++; when I tried to compile code, G++ set fussy did not complain, but GCC set to fussy did.

Comment: @PiotrS., Let me add some relevant text on that usage. I don't think it's nearly as common as the usage mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I'd just like to make sure that by `struct Composite` you mean `struct Composite *`?

Comment: @DeanSeo: Well, both, I suppose.  It introduces `struct Composite` as a type, and therefore `struct Composite *` as a pointer to that type.  But because `struct Composite` was not mentioned prior to the function prototype, it is a mistake in C (so GCC complains: `cc.c:2:19: error: ‘struct Composite’ declared inside parameter list [-Werror]
 void visit(struct Composite *, Component *);
cc.c:2:19: error: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want [-Werror]`; line 1 contained `typedef struct Component Component;`).

Comment: *"if the class being declared is not found, it will be declared in the namespace containing the function"* though it's still an incomplete type

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Appreciated.

Comment: @PiotrS., Yes, it's still an incomplete type and trying to use it like a complete type in the function will fail if it gets to that point.