# What is the name for a Pointer like class Bar *bar

Tags: c++, pointers, forward-declaration

A Simple Example:

```
void foo(class Bar * bar) {
    foo2(bar);
}

void foo2(Bar * bar) {
    bar->a++;
}
```

The Pointer used in foo2 is a standard Pointer to the class Bar.
OK - The Pointer used in foo is also a pointer to the class Bar. But the class Bar must not be known at this place.

I can't find the correct naming for the argument of foo. It is a pointer to an anonymous class? What is the correct name for the `class Bar *bar`?

Comment: What, you mean like a *forward declaration*?

Comment: Your question is unclear, especially the declaration of `Bar` is missing. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @Michael Walz I don't think the declaration of `Bar` is relevant for this question.

Comment: It's also a "standard" pointer to `Bar`.

Comment: Nothing special about `foo()`. If `class Bar` is forward declared (i.e. incomplete class e.g. `class Bar;`) then `foo2(bar);` is valid but `bar->a++;` not. That is because incomplete types may be used as pointer only.

Comment: @Detonar Of course it is. We need to know what _"the class Bar must not be known at this place"_ is supposed to mean - presumably that they only forward-, not fully, declared the class - but it's not useful without full clarity on what is being asked.

Comment: @Scheff Incomplete types can also be used by reference and as the return/argument types in function declarations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When can I use a forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration)

Comment: @underscore_d Yepp. And all this is nicely explained in the link which is provided in the answer of [Mixhab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47903014/7478597). I would've been even better if he had quoted the relevant parts...

Comment: probably a better duplicate: [Why is a forward declaration in a function declaration allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31422807/why-is-a-forward-declaration-in-a-function-declaration-allowed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is `forward declaration`.

You can read about it [in the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class) or [in a different post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c).

From the documentation:

`Declares a class type which will be defined later in this scope. Until the definition appears, this class name has incomplete type. This allows classes that refer to each other.`

Comment: The link to cppreference.com is appropriate. You could improve your answer by copying and quoting the relevant parts from there. (And there is a typo: "codumentation" instead of "documentation" - though it's funny...)

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Scheff. I added a "teaser" from the documentation. I personally like concise answers in this site and add reference for whoever want to broaden their horizons , especially when those 2 links have very good explanations.

Comment: When I was new in SO (not so long ago) somebody taught me that quoting should be preferred (and links may be added additionally) as "links get rotten over time". That's true. Over time, I found some good answers where links were broken...

Answer (score 2):

I would call this an *inline forward class declaration* but i don't think there is a special name for this.

It just tells that there is a class `Bar` so it can be used in this scope.

You **CAN'T** call members of `Bar` with just this. all it says is *there is*, it doesn't says what it is. `Bar` is a *incomplete type* like this.